# SDL2 + openGL ES 2.0 frame rate performance boost with less CPU load

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, opengl-es-2.0

I am developing on a linux system using latest (at the moment) SDL2 (2.0.8) + openGL ES 2.0 (GLSL 1.0) eventually targeting a raspberry pi 3 board. I have so far done a few things like drawing text with freetype, drawing lines, text boxes (editable), text lists, waveform boxes (all i need to pass to a function is an array of vertices) and other shapes with glDrawArrays(). Now, there are things that need to be refreshed at, let's say, 10 times per sec and others that need 1 time per second. What would be the best approach to skip re-rendering everything at the rate of 10 times per sec? Because obviously openGL works by drawing everything from scratch on every 'frame'. However i know and you know that other approaches exist that include: rendering on top of the screen you already have or taking a screenshot and rendering on top of it only the fast changing things as well as other solutions. What do you thing would be the best approach to skip re-doing everything before calling SDL_GL_SwapWindow() ? How can i take a screen shot and render it on the invisible buffer then render only the fast changing objects and then call SDL_GL_SwapWindow() ?

[This is a screen shot of the app so far drawing basic things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhIrK.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenGL is a one trick pony, it writes to a screen and then you display it. It does not remember what it wrote or where (that is up to you). You can do what it is you want, but you will need to store (in some manner) the location of those bits of screen that need updating at the various times, and a way to craft/blit the update so that it matches the surrounding screen when you update the screen. The opengl wiki has information about it, but it isn't something you find in general tutorials. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

i eventually had to realize that i should not have posted the question in the first place but since this is a place where people learn from others i now feel somewhat nicer :) . So, the thing i had to do was to simply stop clearing the invisible buffer (i will call it that for simplicity) and render on top of it only controls that change. Those that change are updated by covering the area that they take by a rectangle and then draw new stuff on that area. I have already done it and the frame rate just 'exploded'. I do not really think that there is a better approach since the way i do it requires no action at all. All i had to do was to add a few if conditions that selectively rendered or skipped every time the execution reached the point where functions iterate through the controls that have to be drawn on screen and therefore decide what to render and what not. However a well thought set of structures is required for every control instead of declaring and defining endlessly global variables which will only makes things confusing and difficult to maintain.

Regards to all.